# how to call constructor in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, constructor, call

i am new to iPhone developer,

i want to call constructor manually, how should i call ?

here is my code snippet,

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {


        CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("ePubTutorial.epub"), NULL, NULL);
        pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
        CFRelease(pdfURL);
        self.pageNumber = 1;
        self.backgroundColor = nil;
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Thanks In Advance !!**

Comment: the term in this case is *initializer*, not *constructor*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use that init method. Example:

```
[[yourClass alloc]initWithFrame:yourFrame];
```

And I'd recommend buying some books and reading them, they do help

Answer (score 0):

the method containing init with it's name is constructor in iphone. you will call it as

```
Object* obj = [[Object alloc] initWithFrame:theFram];
```